# Sending facebook notifications that redirects to my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I have a server which is configured with my facebook app to send notifications to users when they facebook connect.

Currently, the notification redirects to the canvas which redirects to my website :)
I tried to submit review of a new og action and they dont want me to do it.

Is it a common problem ?
Do you have a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: What they dont want you to do?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features: _“11. The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and onto an external site.”_

Comment: I've been given an app that already redirects from the canvas. I want to add open graph actions to the app, but they don't want to accept it anymore. I think I should put some fake app in the canvas for the time of the review.